# Calculate the area under $f(x) = \sqrt x$ on $[0,4]$ by computing the lower Riemann sum for $f$ with the given partition

Tags: real-analysis, area, integer-partitions

Where $x_i = \dfrac{4i^2}{n^2}$ and letting $n \rightarrow \infty$

I don't know how and where to begin.

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is an increasing function in this interval, so it attains its minimum on any subinterval at the left border.

Comment: Suggest you put in something you tried, to avoid downvotes if nothing else.

Comment: You may also consider this picture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FunktionUmkehrIntegral2.svg) and compute $\int_{0}^{2}x^2\,dx$ that is way easier, given the identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Comment: @jack ok why should I follow that? I am still not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i) \, \Delta x_i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{4i^2}{n^2}} \left( \frac{4(i+1)^2}{n^2} - \frac{4i^2}{n^2} \right).
$$

Etc.  Why don't you know where to begin?  Are you unaware of what Riemann sums are?  If so, maybe you could ask about that.

Comment: I guess I am forgetting my calculus 2

Comment: It sounds as if maybe you should review what Riemann sums are.